# Unauthorized to use WebClient on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient, http-status-code-401

I'm using WebClient to get the content of a specific page. When I try this with the code below, I get a syntax error which says `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized`.

I'm running my project on localhost (using Visual Studio 2015 Community and ASP.Net) and trying to get the content of this page "http://admin:admin@192.168.0.100/Monarch/syncconnect/sdk.aspx?command=GetStatus". I don't think you guys can see it, but this is basically all that the page contains:

`<body>ENC1:RTSP,READY,ENC2:RECORD,READY,NAME:Monarch HDX</body>`

My computer and that page both are connected to the same router (if that is usefull information).

How do I work around this error? Or is there a better way to get the content?

**Code**

`var client = new WebClient();
            string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://admin:admin@192.168.0.100/Monarch/syncconnect/sdk.aspx?command=GetStatus");
            loaded.Text = downloadString;`

Comment: It's not that you're unauthorized to use WebClient. It's that your WebClient isn't providing the correct authentication to the site that you're trying to connect to. That's what an HTTP 401 response means.

Comment: Can you open this link in your browser, that is, is admin:admin the correct user/pass?

Comment: @HaukurHaf Yes, I can, that's how I discovered what's in the page

Comment: Ok, maybe the WebClient does not support passing user/pass via the URL.  I have never tested that myself.  Try this instead:

client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin", "admin", ""); before calling DownloadString()

Comment: @HaukurHaf Do I still have to provide the username and password in the url?

Comment: no, you should not have to do that.

Comment: Okay, please put it in an answer, so I can accept the answer, because it works :D

Comment: Done, glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin", "admin", "");
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://192.168.0.100/Monarch/syncconnect/sdk.aspx?command=GetStatus");
loaded.Text = downloadString;
```

Comment: Thanks! :D This helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```